# Setting a HTTP user agent with mechanize?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm having difficulty setting the `user-agent`. As you can see my custom `user_agent_alias` is not being returned. Can someone please explain why this isn't working and how I can fix this?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'

m = Mechanize.new
m.user_agent_alias = 'My Custom User Agent'
page = m.get("http://whatsmyuseragent.com/")
html = Nokogiri::HTML(page.body)
puts html.xpath('//*[(@id = "body_lbUserAgent")]').map(&:content)
```

Below is the "user agent" being returned (not what I set):

> **Mechanize/2.7.3 Ruby/2.0.0p353 (http://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was that `user_agent_alias` requires a specific type. All acceptable types are as follows:

- Linux Firefox (3.6.1)
- Linux Konqueror (3)
- Linux Mozilla
- Mac Firefox (3.6)
- Mac Mozilla
- Mac Safari (5)
- Mac Safari 4
- Mechanize (default)
- Windows IE 6
- Windows IE 7
- Windows IE 8
- Windows IE 9
- Windows Mozilla
- iPhone (3.0)
- iPad
- Android (Motorola Xoom)

***Working code:***

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

m = Mechanize.new
m.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari 4'
page = m.get("http://whatsmyuseragent.com/")
html = Nokogiri::HTML(page.body)
puts html.xpath('//*[(@id = "body_lbUserAgent")]').map(&:content)
```

Comment: You can always retrieve the list of supported user_agent_aliases via: `puts Mechanize::AGENT_ALIASES.keys`.  My installation returns
`["Mechanize", "Linux Firefox", "Linux Konqueror", "Linux Mozilla", "Mac Firefox", "Mac Mozilla", "Mac Safari 4", "Mac Safari", "Windows Chrome", "Windows IE 6", "Windows IE 7", "Windows IE 8", "Windows IE 9", "Windows Mozilla", "iPhone", "iPad", "Android", "Mac FireFox", "Linux FireFox"] ` which is only slightly different from @Fab

Comment: OP's question was "...and how to fix". @severin answered how to fix it. Thumbsup for the explanation, though.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually possible to set any user agent string: you have to use the method `Mechanize::Agent#user_agent=` instead of `Mechanize::Agent#user_agent_alias=`.

So if you change your example to:

```
m = Mechanize.new
m.user_agent = 'My Custom User Agent'
page = m.get("http://whatsmyuseragent.com/")
```

Then it works.